# What to do when http header wrongly reports content-length

Tags: c, sockets, https

I am trying to download web pages over https by first downloading the headers with a HEAD request, then parsing to obtain the Content-Length and then using the Content-Length plus some space for headers to allocate memory for a buffer to store results from a GET request. It seems that stackoverflow.com gives a Content-Length that is too small and thus my code segfaults.

I've tried looking through stack overflow past questions to see how to go about dynamically allocating memory to handle pages which misreport their Content-Length but haven't been able to find any suitable answers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define MAX_HEADER_SIZE 8192

/**
 * Main SSL demonstration code entry point
 */
int main() {
    char* host_and_port = "stackoverflow.com:443"; 
    char* head_request = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n"; 
    char* get_request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n"; 
    char* store_path = "mycert.pem"; 
    char *header_token, *line_token, content_length_line[1024];
    char *cmp = "\r\n";
    char *html;
    char *get;
    int content_length;
    size_t i = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_HEADER_SIZE];
    buffer[0] = 0;

    BIO* bio;
    SSL_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    SSL* ssl = NULL;

    /* initilise the OpenSSL library */
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    bio = NULL;
    int r = 0;

    /* Set up the SSL pointers */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
    ssl = NULL;
    r = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, store_path, NULL);

    if (r == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout,"Unable to load the trust store from %s.\n", store_path);
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
    }

    /* Setting up the BIO SSL object */
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    if (!(ssl)) {
        printf("Unable to allocate SSL pointer.\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout); 
        bio = NULL;           
    }
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    /* Attempt to connect */
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, host_and_port);

    /* Verify the connection opened and perform the handshake */
    if (BIO_do_connect(bio) < 1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Unable to connect BIO.%s\n", host_and_port);
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        bio = NULL;
    }

    if (SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK) {
        printf("Unable to verify connection result.\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);            
    }

    if (bio == NULL)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);

    r = -1;

    while (r < 0) {

        r = BIO_write(bio, head_request, strlen(head_request));
        if (r <= 0) {
            if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
                printf("BIO_read should retry test failed.\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);            
                continue;
            }
            /* It would be prudent to check the reason for the retry and handle
            * it appropriately here */
        }
    }

    r = -1;

    while (r < 0) {
        r = BIO_read(bio, buffer, MAX_HEADER_SIZE);
        if (r == 0) {
            printf("Reached the end of the data stream.\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
            continue;
        } else if (r < 0) {
            if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
                printf("BIO_read should retry test failed.\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
                continue;
            }

            /* It would be prudent to check the reason for the retry and handle
            * it appropriately here */
        }
    };
    printf("%s\r\n", buffer);

    header_token = strtok(buffer, cmp);

    while (header_token != NULL)
    {
        //printf ("header_token: %s\n\n", header_token);
        if (strncmp(header_token, "Content-Length:", strlen("Content-Length:")) == 0 
        || strncmp(header_token, "content-length:", strlen("content-length:")) == 0)
        {
            //printf ("header_token %s is equal to Content-Length:\n", header_token);
            strcpy(content_length_line, header_token);
        }
        header_token = strtok(NULL, cmp);
    }

    if (strlen(content_length_line) > 0) 
    {
        line_token = strtok(content_length_line, " ");
        line_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        content_length = atoi(line_token);
        printf ("Content-Length = %d\n", content_length);
    }

    //char get[content_length + MAX_HEADER_SIZE];
    get = malloc((content_length + MAX_HEADER_SIZE)*sizeof(char));
    if (get == NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Out of memory\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    r = -1;

    while (r < 0) {

        r = BIO_write(bio, get_request, strlen(get_request));
        if (r <= 0) {
            if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
                printf("BIO_read should retry test failed.\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);            
                continue;
            }
            /* It would be prudent to check the reason for the retry and handle
            * it appropriately here */
        }
    }

    r = -1;

    while (r) {
        while (r < 0) {
            r = BIO_read(bio, buffer, 4096);
            if (r == 0) {
                printf("Reached the end of the data stream.\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
                continue;
            } else if (r < 0) {
                if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
                    printf("BIO_read should retry test failed.\n");
                    fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                    ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
                    continue;
                }

                /* It would be prudent to check the reason for the retry and handle
                * it appropriately here */
            }
        };
        printf("Received %d bytes\n",r);
        printf("Received total of %ld bytes of %d\n", i+r, content_length);
        memcpy(get+i, buffer, r);
        i += r;
    }
    printf("%s\r\n", buffer);

    /* clean up the SSL context resources for the encrypted link */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    free(get);  

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I would usually expect to be able to print out the full web page but because of the erroneous Content-Length I get the following output and segfault.

```
Received 1752 bytes
Received total of 248784 bytes of 105585

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:404
404     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
```

How should I handle pages that give incorrect Content-Length?

Comment: I'd say this comes down to a combination of defensive programming, and knowing what to trust.  (1) Evidently you can't trust Content-Length. (2) So you need to write code that works even when Content-Length is wrong. (3) So you're going to have to learn the realloc-as-you-go algorithm. (4) Or maybe you don't need to keep the whole response in memory (let alone contiguous memory) at all?

Comment: tIn any case it is just the case of you handling the number of bytes received completely incorrectly in the last loop.

Comment: And **you not asking for Connection: close**.

Comment: Content-length is an optional header, you can't depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-length`  in the response to a `HEAD` request is of no relevance. Only the `Content-length` in the response containing the actual body is relevant (i.e. response to `GET`, `POST`...). And this `Content-length` should be used to read the HTTP body, i.e. first read the HTTP header, determine the length and then read the body as specified. Even if more data could be read they don't belong to the response body.

Apart from that you are doing a HTTP/1.1 request. This means that the server might use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in which case the value of `Content-length` is irrelevant too. Instead chunked encoding takes preference and you need to read all the chunks of the body based on the length of each given chunk.

Comment: My understanding was that the Content-Length in both the HEAD and GET request should be the same.

Comment: The first problem in the question is that the code is totally b0rken and the site in question **does** give the correct content-length, i.e. it does not even work correctly for those responses that it *should* handle.

Comment: @JamesRead: The server is no required to send any `Content-length` in the response to HEAD at all (see RC 7231 section 4.3.2: *"payload header fields
   (Section 3.3) MAY be omitted"*). Moreover the actual length of the body might change when doing the same request multiple times and thus can also change between HEAD and GET. Thus you cannot conclude from the value you get with HEAD what the value with GET will be.

Comment: @Antti Haapala So why does it segfault if the content-length is correct?

Comment: @JamesRead: you fail to reset `r` to `-1` and therefore append the same initial buffer again and again to `get` - and ultimately overflowing `get`.

Comment: @JamesRead if you had included more lines of output from the program it is evident that **every** iteration "receives" 1752 bytes, which is highly unlikely!

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it seems I need to also test if i is greater than content_length and then break out of the loop also. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @JamesRead: Again, you do only a single read  and then add the same `buffer` to `get` again and again.